# Para que servem e por que aninham a tag DIV?

Tags: html5, div

A **TAG** `<div>` é uma das que mais visualizo dentro de um arquivo `HTML`, a mesma é utilizada dentro do início da abertura da **TAG** `<body>` ao fechamento da mesma `</body>`, como por exemplo:

```
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Não consigo entender para que serve exatamente e o porquê de aninharem a mesma...

Comment: Leia apenas o primeiro parágrafo: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div

Comment: A pergunta soa um pouco estranha porque ao perguntar para que serve as `div`s e dizer "_não entendo para que exatamente serve ou o porque colocam div dentro de outra div_" ao meu ver entra um pouco em conflito com o que vc diz aqui "_Div é umas das tags que mais vejo no HTML e que é usado do início ao fim no body_"... ao mesmo tempo que parece não ter nenhum conhecimento de HTML, parece que tem sim conhecimento, mencionando "tags", "body" com propriedade... :D... inclusive escreveu "HTML" em caixa alta... 

Answer (score 8):

Boa parte dessa resposta é baseada em boas práticas, UX, acessibilidade e minha própria opinião.

**O que é a `<div>`**

> The **div** element **has no special meaning** at all. It represents its children. It can be used with the `class`, `lang`, and `title attributes` to mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements.

Tradução: *"O elemento `div` não tem nenhum significado especial. Representa seus filhos. Ele pode ser usado com os atributos `class`, `lang` e `title` para marcar a semântica comum a um grupo de elementos consecutivos."*

Fonte da documentação oficial W3C https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-div-element.html

div = *div*isor serve para dividir o layout em blocos. E logicamente pode receber estilos CSS e receber comportamentos dos mais diversos.

---

**Mas por que usam tanto a `<div>`?**

Acredito que vemos tantas div no HTML por que muitas vezes elas são usadas de forma errada, por exemplo para construir tabelas, menus, e até formulários... Não  vou generalizar, mas se você ver no HTML um elemento que por *default* é do tipo block, e está com o `display` setado para`display:inline`, provavelmente ele está sendo usado de forma errada, estruturalmente falando.

Acredito que nos próximos anos você vai ver cada vez menos `div`, sabe por quê? Porque agora o HTML 5 é semântico. Agora podemos dividir nosso layout por `<sections>`, `<articles>`, `<footers>`, `<headers>`, `<nav>` etc. Com o `display:flex` não precisamos mais usar `display:inline-block` nem  `float:left` nas `div` para alinhar uma ao lado da outra e ainda ter que fazer a "gambiarra" do *clearfix* pra não deixar o layout quebrar.

Layout semântico sem precisar de `div`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro motivo para vermos tantas `div` é por causa desses `frameworks` que entregam componentes prontos. Você vai colocando um componente dentro do outro, e com isso cria um monte de `divs` desnecessárias... Qualquer site em wordpress por exemplo costuma ter um número imenso de `divs` por serem na maioria um template cheio de componentes e plugins.

Exemplo div na construção de componente Bootstrap:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resumindo, `<table>` é para fazer tabela, `<form>` é para fazer formulário, se quer uma `div` ao lado da outra não use `float`, `float` não é para isso. E use as tags semântica do HTML5 `<nav>` para menus, `<footers>` para rodapé etc. E se precisar use uma div ou outra dentro desses elementos para dividir os elementos em blocos se preciso.

Answer (score 4):

**Resumo**

> O elemento de divisão `HTML <div>` é um **container genérico** para **conteúdo de fluxo**, que de certa forma **não representa nada**. Ele pode ser **utilizado** para **agrupar elementos para fins de estilos** (usando `class` ou `id`), **ou porque** eles **compartilham valores de atributos**, como `lang`. **Ele deve ser utilizado somente quando não tiver outro elemento de semântica** (tal como `<article>` ou `<nav>`).

**Tag HTML** `<div>`

> A **tag** `<div>` **define uma divisão ou seção em um documento** `HTML`. O elemento `<div>` é **frequentemente usado como um contêiner para outros elementos** `HTML` para **estilizá-los com** `CSS` **ou para executar determinadas tarefas com** `JavaScript`.

**Dica**

> O elemento `<div>` é usado com muita frequência junto com `CSS` para layout de uma página da web.

**Nota**

> Por padrão, os navegadores sempre colocam uma quebra de linha antes e depois do elemento `<div>`. No entanto, isso pode ser alterado com `CSS`.

**Representação Gráfica**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[FONTE OFICIAL - W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)

[FONTE OFICIAL - DEVELOPER MOZZILA](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)

Answer (score 0):

A Div é uma tag HTML. Mais precisamente um elemento que se comporta como um bloco. Muito utilizada para estruturar o leiaute / template de uma página.

No HTML existem tags que se comportam como Bloco e como linha.

Exemplos de elementos que se comportam como linha:

```
- <a>, <span>, <strong>, <b>...
```

Exemplos de elementos que se comportam como blocos:

```
- <div>, <p>, <section>, <article>...
```

Uma das formas de identificar quando o elemento se comporta como Bloco é verificando se ele quebra uma linha quando é declarado junto a outro elemento.

Como?

Declare:

```html
<a href="#">Link aqui</a> <div>Um conteúdo aqui</div>
```

Observe que a renderização no navegador será a seguinte:

Link aqui
Um conteúdo aqui

Com isso é possível concluir que o `<a>` é um elemento que se comporta como linha, porque ele não quebrou uma linha ao ser renderizado, já o elemento `<div>` é um elemento em bloco, porque ao ser renderizado ele não continuou na mesma linha que o `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

A tags "DIV" define  **div**isão ou seção em um documento HTML. O uso da mesma ajuda no entendimento do código, é considerado um técnico de UX e boa prática de desenvolvimento.

É importante para separar os "grupos" de textos e ter um código pego legível.